# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bigchaindb_driver'

Tags: python, django, ipdb, bigchaindb

I'm using Django with Python 3.6.3 and Windows 7. I'm trying to install BigchainDB driver and want to use IPDB.
I run this `pip install bigchaindb` and I guess it executed successfully.
I import bigchaindb_driver like that `from bigchaindb_driver import BigchainDB`. But when i run the server using `python manage.py runserver` it gives me this error.
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bigchaindb_driver'**

My code look like this:

> ```
> import os
> from bigchaindb_driver import BigchainDB> 
> tokens = {}
> tokens['app_id'] = 'my-app-id'
> tokens['app_key'] = 'my-apy-key'
> bdb = BigchainDB('https://test.ipdb.io', headers=tokens)
> ```

My questions are:

- If i want to use IPDB, i still have to install bigchainDB on my local machine?
- What exactly i need to start a project on bigchainDB, as i have installed MongoDB and RethinkDB but i don't exactly know weather i need them or not.

Comment: Are you sure `bigchaindb` is the right package to install. Try `bigchaindb_driver`.

Comment: 'pip3 install bigchaindb' will install only the bigchain DB. if you want to connect bigchain DB from python, you need to install python bigchaindb driver. First install dependencies libffi & libssl-dev and then install the driver 'pip3 install bigchaindb_driver'

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install the BigchainDB Python driver using `pip install bigchaindb_driver`.

In your Python code, there should be no `>` at the end of the line `from bigchaindb_driver import BigchainDB>`, i.e. it should just be:

`from bigchaindb_driver import BigchainDB`

More info: [BigchainDB Python Driver](https://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/py-driver/en/latest/quickstart.html)